# why I got Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length in server but on local everything is good?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when I test my project in server I've got error `"Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"` but in local everything is good.
Notice:I'm using the same connection string in server and local.what is differences between local and server why I've got it error in server but I didn't get on local.

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string dt_az, string dt_ta, int? workHouseId)
    {
        string htmlRow = string.Empty;
        int date_az, date_ta;
        var dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_az);
        var dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_ta);
        ViewBag.WorkhouseId = new SelectList(db.Workhouses, "WorkhouseId", "WorkhouseName");
        date_az = Convert.ToInt32(dt_az.Replace("/", ""));
        date_ta = Convert.ToInt32(dt_ta.Replace("/", ""));

        var workersInBetweenTwoDates = db.WorkerTimes.Where(w => w.DateWork_int >= date_az && w.DateWork_int <= date_ta && w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId).OrderBy(w => w.DateWork_int).ToList();

        foreach (DateTime day in EachDay(dateFrom, dateTo))
        {

            var shortDateWithoutTime = day.Date.ToShortDateString().Trim();
            string customDate = string.Empty;
            string dayy= string.Empty;
            string month= string.Empty;
            string year= string.Empty;

                 dayy = shortDateWithoutTime.Substring(0, 2).Trim();
                 month = shortDateWithoutTime.Substring(2, 2).Trim();
                 year = shortDateWithoutTime.Substring(4, 4).Trim();
                customDate = year + month + dayy;
                var stringDateToInt = Convert.ToInt32(customDate);
                //var s= stringDateToInt.ToString().

                var workHour = workersInBetweenTwoDates.Where(w => w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId && w.DateWork_int.ToString() == customDate).Sum(w => w.WorkHour);
                var shabaneh = workersInBetweenTwoDates.Where(w => w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId && w.DateWork_int.ToString() == customDate).Sum(w => w.ExtraNight);
                var roozaneh = workersInBetweenTwoDates.Where(w => w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId && w.DateWork_int.ToString() == customDate).Sum(w => w.ExtraDaily);
                var sentry = workersInBetweenTwoDates.Where(w => w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId && w.DateWork_int.ToString() == customDate).Sum(w => w.Sentry);
                var extraNightSentry = workersInBetweenTwoDates.Where(w => w.WorkhouseId == workHouseId && w.DateWork_int.ToString() == customDate).Sum(w => w.ExtraNightSentry);
                //< td > " + workersInBetweenTwoDates.Select(w => w.DateWork_slash).FirstOrDefault() + " </ td >< td > " + workersInBetweenTwoDates.Select(w => w.CompleteDay).FirstOrDefault() + " </ td >
                htmlRow += "<tr><td>" + day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</td><td>" + workHour + "</td><td>" + shabaneh + "</td><td>" + roozaneh + "</td><td>" + sentry + "</td><td>" + extraNightSentry + "</td></tr>";

        }
        ViewBag.Row = htmlRow;
        return View();
    }
```

---

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
        {
            for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
                yield return day;
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?  What are the relevant variable values when that happens?

Comment: I wish also know what are the datetime settings of your server. Your manipulation of date strings assumes a particular format that could not be the same on your server. (For example ddMMyy is a 6 chars format and you ask for a 8 chars format)

Comment: @steve,My date format is jalali(persian date) it is not Gregorian date.I've tested on visual studio it's ok,also I've got dates from datetimepicker kendo ui

Comment: However, in the code above, the only place where I can imagine such error is when you handle the substring from the variable returned by EachDay. I would try to add some logging to check what that function returns when run on the server. (It will be good if you also add that code here)

Comment: @Steve,I've  added EachDay function

Comment: Yes I see it, nothing particular then. I can only recommend to log the value of _shortDateWithoutTime_ when your code runs on the server.